# SwiftUI ScrollView Scrolls to Previous TextField

Tags: swift, swiftui

If I have a few `TextField`s within a `ScrollView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var text = ""
  
var body: some View {
  ScrollView {
    VStack {
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
      
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
      
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
      
      
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
      
      
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
      
      
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
      
      
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
      
      
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
      
      
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
    
    VStack {
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
      
      
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
      
      
      
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
      
      
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
      
      
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
      
      
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
      
      
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
      
      
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
      
      
      TextField("1", text: $text)
        .frame(height: 55)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
    
    
  }
  .padding(.horizontal)
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
  .background(Color.white)
  }
}
```

And I click the first `TextField` and then I scroll down and click one of the latter `TextField`s, the `ScrollView` jumps back to the previous `TextField` that had focus instead of keeping the currently focused `TextField` in view. Is this normal behavior or an error? If it's normal, how do I prevent it?

It's a pretty jarring experience when you scroll down and click on a `TextField` and the `ScrollView` jumps to the top.

Comment: Not reproducible with Xcode 13 / iOS 15 - works as expected.

Comment: Hmm I guess it was a bug. I am using XCode 12.5.1 and iOs 14

Comment: Unable to reproduce as well. Using iOS 14.5 on Xcode beta 13.

Comment: this issue doesn't reproduces on a simulator, but reproduces on a real device=) I don't have a device with beta so can't check if it was fixed in iOS 15. Still not sure why you guys testing on beta versions when is not related to beta? It's still a month until release and even after that supporting iOS 14 will be needed for a long time, in case it was fixed in iOS 15

Answer (score 0):

This really looks like a bug, and I was able to reproduce it even with a `List`.

After that I really haven't expected that, but switching from `VStack` to `LazyVStack` **works**.

Looks like in this case old text field is not on the screen anymore so it's not causing this strange animation. And, unlike `List`, looks like `LazyVStack` is holding info about selected text field without saving actual view.